# Java Persistence API(JPA) - Overriding MappedSuperClass's attributes

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

I have the following questions

1. I have the '@Id' annotated field as part of my '@MappedSuperClass' and I am letting all my entities extend the MappedSuperClass.Now,how do I override the super class 'id' if I have to define a composite primary key for my entity...ie.How do I ask my entity to use its composite primary key annotated as @EmbeddedId instead of the @Id annotated field inherited from the MappedSuperClass? Will the @EmbeddedId annotation in my entity automatically over-ride the superclass's @Id ?
2. I have made a few fields (which are shared by most of the entities in my schema) as part of my MappedSuperClass. Now how do I avoid those fields getting added as columns if few of the entities don't need them ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] How do I ask my entity to use its composite primary key annotated as @EmbeddedId instead of the @Id annotated field inherited from the MappedSuperClass? Will the @EmbeddedId annotation in my entity automatically over-ride the superclass's @Id ?

AFAIK, you can't. So don't inherit from your entity superclass in this case, use another entity superclass.

> I have made a few fields (which are shared by most of the entities in my schema) as part of my MappedSuperClass. Now how do I avoid those fields getting added as columns if few of the entities don't need them ?

Well, again, don't inherit from the entity superclass that holds these fields and use another entity superclass.

Answer (score 0):

JPA provides `attribute-override` to override the mappings for both embedded or mappedsuperclass fields.

For Annotations you can use the `@AttributeOverride` annotation within the java class.
For multiple attributes you can use the `@AttributeOverrides` annotation which contains an array of the `@AttributeOverride` annotation.